# Is it safe to use the same Google account to communicate with users and for AdSense and analytics?

Tags: email, gmail

Should i have 2 separate accounts, one to communicate with the users of the website and sending automated emails with gmail like account confirmations, password resets, etc. And one account for analytics, adSense and all that ?

Are there security risks given the fact that a lot of people will know the gmail address, other than spam emails and all that, or is it just better to have separate accounts?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem using the same email (other then spam), as long as you don't distribute the login credentials. If your site needs credentials for the automated mails, it would be better to have separate account just for that, so that if your site is breached, your main gmail account is not.

Answer (score 0):

I think there isn't an inherent security issue with by using one account for both PR/Marketing and AdSense + analytics. However it would be best if you think about a long term solution here.

Whatever you business/organization may be, you might grow to the point where you will be doing or assigning separate duties to separate team/individuals. It's always best to plan ahead for when you'll (hopefully) be exercising proper security hygiene and separation of duty principles. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_duties

Some issues that you might have by making your main account public are:

- You may be more prone to phishing & spam
- You might experience brute-force attacks more often

NOTE: If you're using an old email for everything, it's always a good idea to check if your email/password has leaked due to a data breach in the following websites:

https://hacked-emails.com/
https://haveibeenpwned.com/

Good question.
Stay safe :)